# How to replace characters that have already been printed in a previous line

Tags: python, function, printing, replace

I am trying to make a game similar to [this](http://candies.aniwey.net/) in Python (3.3.2 on Windows). I think that most of the programming is fairly basic and so it will be easy for me as beginner. What I can't understand is how to have a line of code that is constantly being changed while remaining in the same location (I am trying to describe the amount of candies that you have[if you look the line stays in the same place yet the physical str changes]). I understand that you will have to do something like:

```
candiesNbrDisplay = 'You have ' + str(candiesNbrOwned) + ' candies!'
candiesNbrOwned = candiesNbrOwned + 1
time.sleep( 1)
```

but how do you change the number without [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6utYi.jpg)!

Comment: On Unix, you'd use CR (carriage return) without a line feed (LF or NL) to move the cursor back to the start of the line so that the next output overwrites the previous one.  That might work on Windows too.

Comment: Example in code? Not really picking up what your putting down...ELI5 just started programming so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jonathan suggested using a CR at the end of each line. You can do this by passing an extra parameter to `print`:

```
candies = 0
while True:
    print('You have', candies, 'candies!', end='\r')
    time.sleep(1)
    candies += 1
```

Usually, `print` uses a NL (`\n`) character, which means "skip to the next line".

But here, we tell it to use a CR (`\r`) instead, which means "go back to the beginning of the current line". This is what we want.

Unfortunately, this technique only works on the command line, not in IDLE. So you'll have to run the script directly (double-click its icon) for this to work.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Really nailed the ELI5 lol. Any way to make it compatible with IDLE?

Comment: http://imgur.com/O2QRoWL Thanks for that by the way. Is their any for this to be a backround process while the rest of the game is running since i want this to be happening while the rest of the game is still being played out( once again like [Candy Box](http://candies.aniwey.net/)

Comment: I don't think so. The prompt in IDLE isn't a console, it's just a text box that pretends to be one. So it won't support these control codes. But your users will run your program in the console anyway, so it's not a major issue.

Comment: look at edit to second comment please. + code if it doesn't make sense
    candiesNbrOwned = 0
    while repeat<30:
        print ('You have ', str(candiesNbrOwned), ' candies!',                                                                          end='\r') 
        candiesNbrOwned += 1
        time.sleep( .1)

Comment: You can do that using [multithreading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm), but I'd recommend learning much more before trying that. For a beginner project, I'd recommend something simpler like a guessing game.

Comment: Hey, if you found this answer useful, can you accept it please? (Click the tick under the vote buttons)

Answer (score 0):

This works on Unix (Mac OS X 10.8.5, with Python 2.7.2):

```
import time
import sys

for i in xrange(1, 10):
    print "\rThe number of candies is %d and the pile is growing" % i,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
print ""
```

I don't know whether it will work on Windows or with Python 3.